# UserFrosting route to localhost

Tags: php, routes, localhost, userfrosting

I'm just getting into UserFrosting and now wanted to create a route that leads to the localhost of my system through the standard login page but I just can't figure out how that could work with UserFrosting's routing approach or if it even is possible?

Comment: You should add more details, what exact route you want to leads to? What do you means by Localhost? What have you tried so far?

Comment: basically I want UserFrosting to work like in front of a React application in the end, so the user managment is taken care of by userfrosting and the rest is React, so now I wanted to try to create a route from the standard sign in page of UserFrosting to a local site that is not a sprinkle of UserFrosting. So the route would be port localhost:3001. Maybe this question sounds completely dumb and I'm missing something big here I don't know

Comment: This should answer part of your question. Just need to hardcode the URL I guess : https://learn.userfrosting.com/recipes/custom-login-page#changing-the-post-login-destination